# Constantly update .txt file with title of a window in Linux?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, window-manager, wmctrl

I have an application with a window title that, every second, I want to update a .txt file with that window title. I have been trying to pull this off in bash with `wmctrl -l`, but I can't get anywhere.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:** Sorry for not supplying more context! I want to use this .txt file to constantly update a Text Source in OBS Studio. I'm on Antergos (Arch) with XFCE.

Comment: If you tell us a little bit about the use case and what GUI you have, someone might have a solution for you. Either for how to achieve what you're asking, or a better way to complete the task you need that .txt file for.

Comment: Sorry! I'll add that to the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) would work well for that; it should be easy to find in almost any distribution's package manager.

First you have to find the window id -- I'm using the active window as an example in the script -- then you can read the window title from that and forward it to a file every second.

```
#!/bin/bash 

# find the window id
WID=$(xdotool getactivewindow)

while true; do
    # save the window title into a file
    xdotool getwindowname $WID > $HOME/window-title-info.txt
    sleep 1
done
```